# How to attach token when query the firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

Ok, I came from using REST API to Login and Get Data from Firestore with the rule that require auth user to read and write. Using HTTP Get and Attach the token I get from signIn.

Now, I try to use Angularfire to query the data from Firestore, how can I attach auth token to

```
afs.collection('items', ref => ref.where('size', '==', size)).valueChanges()
```

Comment: You need to be using Firebase Authentication to sign in the user.  When the user is signed in, their ID token will be automatically sent with every query.

Comment: Doug, you mean the authentication method provided in AngularFire right?

Comment: AngularFire just wraps Firebase libraries (including Firebase Authentication). It's the same product in the end.